# How can I exclude all directories with Robocopy that contain "cache"

Tags: batch-file, command-line, robocopy

I am trying to understand better the syntax for excluding directorys in the robocopy command line.

The purpose in this case is to backup user profiles from a mixed XP/Win7 enviroment so I will be dealing with a variety of locations.

By-enlarge most of the directories I want to exclude have the word "cache" in them somewhere. I wish to exclude all directories with "cache" "temp" & "temporary internet files" in its name. That means the "MSO cache""IECompatCache" etc. This is what I have thus far.

```
Robocopy "\\User-computer\c\Documents and Settings\User" "F:\Backups\User\Docs" /MIR /SEC /SECFIX /ZB /XA:SH /XF "Thumbs.db" /XD *temp *cache *"Temporary Internet Files" /XJ /XJD /XJF /R:1 /W:1 /MT:16 /V /NP /LOG:C:\Scripts\User1.log
```

As you might imagine  I am just trying to cut out the useless crude so I can shorten the backup times. No need to backup gigs of useless files from some users browsing habits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have better luck if you put double quotes around each exception, here's the line I found to work in my testing on Windows 7 (Robocopy Version XP010):

```
robocopy d:\test\ d:\test2\ /xd "*cache*" "temporary internet files" "temp" /e
```

Don't forget you can use the `/l` switch to test your job without actually copying anything, it can save a lot of time when troubleshooting this sort of thing.